# How to order line in Crystal report field wise?

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report for company inventory table in C#
The fields of Crystal report is have 2 or more items have
so I want a line to combine both items to have the field 
line between two both item cover.

I tried draw a line in crystal report details section 
but it's not working

Comment: What do you mean by "between two both item cover."?  I don't understand that.

Comment: Show a visual example of what you mean.  No idea what you are asking.